# C# - regex - replace non matching characters

Tags: c#, regex

[there are similar questions but none is giving a valid answer for my needs]

I allow user to input text matching this regex :

```
string validChars = @"^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ0-9\s\.\-\&\,\'\(\)_\/\""\!\:\%]*?$";
```

what I want to do is to remove characters that do NOT match that regex

how can I INVERT the regex so I can do

```
invalidChars  = some_trick_to_invert_regex(validChars); 
text = Regex.Replace(text, invalidChars , "");
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried `string invalidChars = @"[^A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ0-9\s\.\-\&\,\'\(\)_\/\""\!\:\%]";` ?

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you want. On the one hand you preset a single regex, and then say you want the inverse of that regex. That's whole different ball game from what you then show you want (a method that takes any regex and "inverts" it). So which of the 2 are you actually looking for?

Comment: the regex serves as validator, if it does not match, some characters are wrong and we return an error...YET!! we receive data from a third party too...and we have to take them data...I just want to remove non matching character, using the same regex

Comment: the idea is to have only one regex to maintain instead of two, in case we add/remove characters

Comment: Why not only use the inverse regex? For validation you just check if it has 0 matches -> valid. That way you only have 1 regex to maintain (and it's easy to get the inverse of your allowed set) and you gain all the functionality you seem to be looking for?

Comment: Ok, so you have a 3rd party input containing characters you can't handle ... but they are there for a reason, aren't they? Won't you destroy the message by simply removing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can whitelist the characters you want to keep by placing the `^` inside the brackets. Example:

```
string validChars = @"[^A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ0-9\s\.\-\&\,\'\(\)_\/\""\!\:\%]";
string test = "abc#de";
var result = Regex.Replace(test, validChars, ""); //abcde
```